# how to connect to Twilio API with ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

Sorry this is a very basic question so it should be easy to answer!

Using ruby and sinatra, I am trying to connect, via the api, to get details of my calls. The prescribed way to do this by twilio seems to be:

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
# Loop over calls and print out a property for each one
@client.account.calls.list.each do |call|
puts call.sid
puts call.from
puts call.to
```

which works fine and "puts" the data in the terminal. I want to print the results on an HTML page, so I changed the line

```
@client.account.calls.list.each do |call|
```

to

```
@calls = @client.account.calls.list
```

and removed the last 3 lines of the code block above, ie. all the "puts"

then, attempting to print on my index page I included the following:

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
 <h4 style="color: #ff0000;"><%= params['msg'] %></h4>
 <ul>
  <li> <%= call.from %> </li>
  <li> <%= call.to %> </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

The error message says:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

so I am not connecting to twilio it seems even though the code is almost exactly the same as that above which does connect and produce the required results.

Any ideas? All help gratefully received.

Comment: It may be relevant so I am including this now (after the event). The modified second code block starts with:
get '/calls' do and ends with end

Comment: I'm not sure your change of code is relevant. Is your upper code working in your 'index' view?

Comment: no because puts is only for the terminal, not html. Is that right?

Comment: basically I just want to know how to print the result as HTML, that's what it boils down to. So if the first code block works,what do I need to put on index :erb to make it print the HTML there rather than in the terminal?

Comment: Man, are you using erb derective. After getting @calls add line: erb :index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sinatra, do not use instance variables to store connection objects and similar stuff. Instead of `@call`, use the `set` method that enables a user to set such objects to different variables.

The `calls.list` method, as per the code, is defined in the `Twilio::REST::ListResource` module. This returns an array and so, the second part of your code (in the `index.erb`) is correct.

The problem is, when you start using instance variables for storing the connection object, it gets reset in the route and that's what's happening inside the `get do .. end` block.

Change the code to:

```
set :client, Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, account_pass)
# Now, this setting can be accessed by settings.client

get '/calls' do
  @calls = settings.client.account.calls
  erb :index
end

# index.erb

<% @calls.each do |call| %>
...
<% end %>
```

This should work.